# Google Maps API - make callback to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I want to embed a google map using an angular directive. The directive template runs a callback `initMap` which should call the scope `initMap` and create it, but am getting error:

> InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function

How can I call the directive callback from the directive's HTML template?

Parent html file to display map:

```
<my-map></my-map>
```

Directive:

```
( function( ng, app ) {

    'use strict';

    app.directive( 'myMap', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope : {},
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                scope.Template = '/directive_html/map.html';
                scope.initMap = function() {
                     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('contact-map'), { ...
                     ...
                };
           },
           template: "<div ng-include='Template'></div>"
```

Map.html (directive template html)

```
<div id='contact-map'></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

---

```
<script>
    // This is called
    function initMap() {
        // call directive scope.initMap()
    }
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please try removing `async defer` in the `script` tag?

Comment: @SabarishSenthilnathan this did not fix it

Comment: you need to manually initalize map. Your element won't exist when map script loads Suggest using one of the variety of angular map modules to make it simpler though

Comment: The callback in the script loader needs to be  global function which anything in angular scope is not

Comment: @charlietfl Please see above. I've made a script on the template that is called from the callback. How can I call the `scope` function within the directive js from that function?

Comment: @charlietfl then how can you notify when the `maps.googleapis...` has returned? I can't just call the function directly. How would this look?

Answer (score 3):

`initMap` needs to be a global function.

Before I continue with a possible solution, I would highly recommend using the [angular-google-maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/) library.

However, you could do the following:

1. create `initMap` as a global function
2. have a `mapLoadedService` that returns a promise once gmaps initialised
3. `resolve` the promise in `mapLoadedService` on `initMap`

So add the following to your global js:

```
var initMap = function(){    
    var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]')); //your app qs
    var injector = elem.injector();
    var mapLoadedService = injector.get('mapLoadedService');
    mapLoadedService.loaded();
};
```

Add the following service to your angular app:

```
app.factory( 'mapLoadedService', ['$q', function($q) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    this.init = function(){
            return defer.promise;
    };
    this.loaded = function(){
            defer.resolve();
    };
});
```

then in your directive:

```
app.directive( 'myMap', ['$rootScope','mapLoadedService', function($rootScope, mapLoadedService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope : {},
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.Template = '/directive_html/map.html';
                //mapLoadedService returns a promise, that only resolves when google maps lib has loaded and is available globally...
                mapLoadedService.init().then(function(){
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('contact-map'), { });
                });

       },
       template: "<div ng-include='Template'></div>"
    }
});
```

You should also then load the google maps library in your `index.html` or app base.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```